# Estilos no funcionan en Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo problemas con algunos estilos, no se como hacer para que se muestren de buena manera en  internet explorer, nunca he trabajado  con esos estilos.

esto  es para un nav, le cual hace que en internet explorer se despliegue hacia abajo en lugar que ocupe el  100 por ciento  de la pantalla de derecha a izquierda

como podria realizar esto, bueno de igual forma como se podria para safari?

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX les dejo el css XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
 
}

.active {
  background-color:;
  color: ;
 
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
 
}

.dropdown1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
 
}

.dropdown1 .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;

 
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 
}

.dropdown-content1 a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1;
 
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown1:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content1 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown1:hover .dropdown-content1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" style="background-color:#2B2B2B; ">
       <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/hom.png')}}" >{{ __('Home') }}
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" ><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/shop.png')}}" >{{ __('Shop') }}</a>

            <a href="http://signuptest.nikkenlatam.com/indexConsultant/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho  signCon"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Consultant') }}</a>
            <!--<a href="http://172.18.2.194/signup_usa/public/indexConsultant/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Consultant') }}</a>-->

           <a href="http://signuptest.nikkenlatam.com/index/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank"  class="a-ho signCus"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Customer') }}</a>
            <!-- <a href="http://localhost/signup_usa/public/index/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Customer') }}</a>-->

            <a href="https://test.nikken.com/AutoshipNA/?dist={{ $encrypted }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/autoship.png')}}" >{{ __('Autoship') }}</a>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickGen()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/genealogy.png')}}" >{{ __('Genealogy and Broadcast') }}</a>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickGrap()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/graphs.png')}}" >{{ __('Graphs') }}</a>

        </div>
        </div> 

         <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/order.png')}}" >{{ __('Order Entry') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <a href="https://test.nikken.com/AutoshipNA/?dist={{ $encrypted }}" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/autoship.png')}}" >{{ __('Autoship') }}</a>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/shop.png')}}" >{{ __('Shop') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div> 


         <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/singup.png')}}" >{{ __('Sign Up') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">

           <!-- <a href="http://172.18.2.194/signup_usa/public/indexConsultant/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Consultant') }}</a>-->
            <a href="http://signuptest.nikkenlatam.com/indexConsultant/{{ $ids }}"target="_blank" class="a-ho signCon"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Consultant') }}</a>

            <a href="http://signuptest.nikkenlatam.com/index/{{ $ids }}" target="_blank" class="a-ho signCus" ><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/add.png')}}" >{{ __('Customer') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div> 


        <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/reports.png')}}" >{{ __('Reports') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickGrap()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/graphs.png')}}" >{{ __('Graphs') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" id="trackreport" onclick="clickTrack()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/rastreo.png')}}" >{{ __('Tracking') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickWatch()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/watch.png')}}" >{{ __('Watch List') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickUpline()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/upline.png')}}" >{{ __('Upline Listing') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickTax()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/autoship.png')}}" >{{ __('Tax Summary') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickGen()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/genealogy.png')}}" >{{ __('Genealogy and Broadcast') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickComm()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/primary_bonus.png')}}" >{{ __('Commission/Earning Summary') }}</a>
 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" id="inquirybtn" onclick="clickAccount()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/tracking.png')}}" >{{ __('Account inquiry/Tracking') }}</a>

          </div>
        </div> 
       
        <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/events.png')}}" >{{ __('Events') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button> 
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <!--<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickEvents()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/conference.png')}}" >{{ __('Events Calendar') }}</a> -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickEvents()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/conference.png')}}" >See Event</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickCreateEvent()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/conference.png')}}" >Create Event</a> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickConferenceRecording()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/conference_call.png')}}" >Conference Calls and Recordings</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickConference()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/conference_call.png')}}" >{{ __('Conference Call Schedule') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/com.png')}}" >{{ __('Communication') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickNews()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/news.png')}}" >{{ __('News & Information Center') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickFeedback()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/feedback.png')}}" >{{ __('Feedback') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div> 


        <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/tools.png')}}" >{{ __('Business Tools') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickIncentives()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/incentives.png')}}" >{{ __('Incentives') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickVideo()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/video.png')}}" >{{ __('Video Library') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickImage()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/image.png')}}" >{{ __('Image Library') }}</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickDocument()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/document.png')}}" >{{ __('Document Library') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown1">
          <button class="dropbtn"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/global.png')}}" >{{ __('International Business') }} 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a-ho" onclick="clickCountry()"><img class="icon-menu" src="{{asset('img/packs.png')}}" >{{ __('Country Packs') }}</a>
          </div>
        </div> 

      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Con css defines los estilos como lo mencionaste hay algunas propiedades las cuales no son compatibles con internet explorer o safari, ahora lo que quieres hacer, que tu pagina muestre unos estilos en un navegador y se comporte de manera diferente en otro navegador dudo que se pueda hacer con css, para eso debes usar javascript, comenta más detalles del problema para poder ayudarte, mientras te dejo una web donde puedes checar la compatibilidades de las propiedades css. https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @luis_am92 el problema es  ese quisiera poder que el css  que comparte, lo tomara en i explorer que actuen de la misma manera en todos los navegadores.  pero cambia su  comportamiento.

Comment: Puedes añadir también el documento HTML a tu pregunta para hacer pruebas

Comment: @luis_am92 listo es el  html.

Comment: Has resuelto ya tu pregunta? Si no es así, que sepas que Internet Explorer ya no se utiliza (no funciona, no te deja buscar cosas...), y que ahora te dicen de descargar Microsoft Edge. Saludos